# Remove event listener when callback is a class method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to remove an event listener from a canvas element when the callback is a class method (I'm using typescript for this project). This class is responsible for moving an image within a canvas using the cursor. Currently, the events aren't being removed when the quit method is executed.

I would prefer to keep the callbacks as class methods!

```
class MoveTool extends Tool {

   button: HTMLElement;
   canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;  
   isDraggable: boolean;

   public constructor(element : MouseEvent) {

       if(!__states.activeLayer) return;
       super(element);
       this.canvasEditMode();  
       (<HTMLInputElement>this.element.target).parentElement.classList.add('tool-focus');
   }    

   public quit(this : this) {
       (<HTMLInputElement>this.element.target).parentElement.classList.remove('tool-focus');
       document.getElementById(__states.activeLayer).style.cursor = 'pointer';
       this.canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown.bind(this));
       this.canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove.bind(this));
       this.canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp.bind(this));
   }


   public run() {
       this.isDraggable = false;
       this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown.bind(this));
       this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove.bind(this)); 
       this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp.bind(this));
   }

   public mouseDown(event : MouseEvent) : void {
       this.isDraggable = true;
       this.startCur = this.getCursorPosition(event);
   }

   public mouseUp(event : MouseEvent) : void {
       this.isDraggable = false;
   }

   public mouseMove(event: MouseEvent) : MouseEvent {
       if(this.isDraggable) {

           this.current = this.getCursorPosition(event);

           if(!(this.current.x > 0 - this.image.width 
                && this.current.x < this.canvas.width + this.image.width
                && this.current.y > 0 - this.image.height 
                && this.current.y < this.canvas.height + this.image.height
               )
           ) return;         

           this.currentX = this.startCur.x === this.current.x 
               ? this.currentX
               : this.startCur.x > this.current.x 
                   ? this.currentX - (this.startCur.x - this.current.x) 
                   : this.currentX + (this.current.x - this.startCur.x);


           this.currentY =  this.startCur.y === this.current.y
               ? this.currentY
               : this.startCur.y > this.current.y 
                   ? this.currentY - (this.startCur.y - this.current.y) 
                   : this.currentY + (this.current.y - this.startCur.y);   

           setInterval(() => {
               this.clearCanvas();
               this.context.drawImage(this.image, this.currentX, this.currentY);          
           }, 1000/30);        

       }
       return event;
   }
}
```

Comment: To remove the event listener you are going to need to provide the exact same function provided to `addEventListener`. `bind` creates a new function everytime you call it, so in your examples they are never the same function.

Comment: Thanks @MinusFour, do you have any ideas How I can go about this, without creating functions outside of the class, that both the run and quit methods can use?

Comment: Just store the new function coming out of `bind` in the object instance. Most will prefer to bind their methods to the instance in the constructor if the methods of the class must absolutely be bound to the instance at all times.